# How Can i view the contents of a DBF file?

Tags: centos-7, dbf

`dbview filename` --> no output

dbf filename :

```
[mukesh@centos Others]$ dbf --view-info  0AB701AF19CDCD4DE0D687B870E437D90727CE4B9DE6ABBA5EB46495BED599C9D8E6D0C06B4801CC7D591AB2C2E75A94146D6671C85913944E1B7E8478Z
dBase Reader and Converter V. 0.8.3.1, (c) 2002 - 2004 by Bjoern Berg

-- File statistics
dBase version.........:      FoxBase+/dBASE III+ (without memo)
Date of last update...:      1908-00-08
Number of records.....:      1767985152 (69615000d)
Length of header......:      22116 (5664d)
Record length.........:      25961 (6569d)
Columns in file.......:      690 
Rows in file..........:      1767985152

+---------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| field name    | type  | field adress  | length    | field dec.    |
+---------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|         nId$  |   f   | 32612d38  |  97       |  52       |
|   d71bbafd4       |   d   | 67756265  |  73       |  83       |
|         274       |   a   |    36567  |  49       |  53       |
|        erid   |   2   | 64000b32  | 101       |  98       |
|       |   c   | 6e6f6974  |  73       | 100       |
|          on   |   P   | 57656761  | 105       | 116       |
|     nsCWS �   |   �   | 3c099ba4  | 148       | 223       |
|  �,�F��
          ��c   |           | 7e6a5921  | 149       | 148       |
...................AND SO ON.................
```

Tried with libre office calc and writer as well but it does not open

Comment: Give [`dbfdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbfdump) a shot and/or check out [`dbview`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbview) too and ensure you are using correct options.

Comment: The file looks like it's corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way is to use Libreoffice Calc to open the file.

But from the print you showed it is very clear that the file itself has some incompatibility, whether through corruption of mismatched character sets.

Original DBF files are all just plan ASCII.  There was no support for unicode, for instance.

These funny characters in your example look like it is trying to display  unicode.

Forcing it to UTF-8 might help.  In a case like that you would want to then delete "stange" records and see if you can recover the rest of the file.

I hope you have a good backup of the original to compare with.